I am trying to set up parental controls for myself. Options that can't be accessed/modifed once set?
It is essential that I have administrative rights to my computer. I've been using NextDNS. It works great on my phone because I can have a friend password protect NextDNS' access. However, it can't be password protected and is easily disabled on MacBook. Using a combination of Bartender and an app locker didn't resolve the issue either.
Suggestions? Alternative parental controls? etc.

I think we’re missing the bigger picture here. Why is DNS something you need to lock away beyond your reach?

If you have Admin rights to any Mac you can do anything to it. There is no way to lock out an admin user. Parental Controls require someone to have access to everything. Unless you are willing to give that up there is little or nothing that can be done.

@bmike it's the parental control within NextDNS that I like.

Why not configure your router to use this DNS service and optionally block other requests?
That way your Mac is unable to alter the router since local administrators don’t get the ability to change the router.
Most “self control” apps that have been suggested on this site focus on time limits for running apps and disabling network for a period of time before resetting as opposed to locking a network setting that an admin can easily work around by dropping a new network interface on an existing network or choosing an app that bypasses the system DNS settings.

Yes, I've tried setting the DNS on the router... and really, I don't know about those work around methods without reading about them more, so it would potentially work for me because I am "unaware of them."
However, NextDNS allows a custom configuration that I prefer and I am not sure I am able to use the custom configuration at the router level.

The only thing you can do that you can't undo is secure erase of disks or files.  Trying to use technology to protect you from yourself is futile.
But if you are trying to prevent a non-admin user of your Mac from changing something that can't be made admin-only, you could create a root-owned script executable by only the wheel group, and have it run frequently in a cron job.
That way, if the hypothetical other user changes it, the script changes it back the next time it runs.
